# Firebase Dynamic URL not working with my Wix page

Tags: firebase, dynamic, hyperlink, hosting, velo

I've implemented all the Firebase Requirements in order to use Dynamic Links with my custom domain. The A records, and the TXT information are both added, however now my website is not working.

[image]

My Firebase Hosting tab tells me that the www.mydomain.com is connected, however the image above tells me otherwise, here's my Firebase Hosting information:

[image]

Here's my DNS information on my Wix page

[image]

Note: Sorry about the heavy editing, I don't know exactly what is and what is not sensitive information

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @tfad334, no I actually wasn´t able, also think twice if Wix is a solution if you really want to use Firebase to manage your backend

Comment: Yeah, I've come to that conclusion as well. Thanks for caring to respond.